# passing from controller to view in Grails

Tags: grails

I am trying to pass a collection from my controller to view like so:

```
   def index() {
    childInstance = Child.get(params.id)

    if(childInstance){

       System.out.println("CHILD" + childInstance.firstname)

        def messages = currentUserTimeline(childInstance)
            [profileMessages: messages, childInstance: childInstance]
    }
    else{
   def messages = currentUserTimeline(null)
        [profileMessages: messages]
        System.out.println("ALL " + messages)
    }
}
```

The if works but the else docent it sends profileMessages as a null object.
if i add

```
render template: 'profileMessages', collection: messages, var: 'profileMessage'
```

to the else this works but i want to pass everything to the view and not render it in the controller.

in the view i am using :

```
<g:render template="profileMessages" collection="${profileMessages}" var="profileMessage"/>
```

Any ideas why it works in the if and not in the else when sent to the view?
 FYI i have added

```
[profileMessages: messages, childInstance: null]
```

to the else with no luck and null is allowed and does work in the

```
currentUserTimeline(null)
```

because

```
render template: 'profileMessages', collection: messages, var: 'profileMessage'
```

works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map with the model must be the last commandin the block, so move the System.out.println() above the map.

And it also helps, if you use:

```
return [ profileMessage: message ]
```

BTW ... use log4j instead of System.out.println ;-)